# Vonage Api Call Function

Tags: node.js, api, voip, voice, vonage

Hey I got my code to receive calls but for some reason when I run the script it doesn’t place an out going call. I am not getting no error message or anything it just simply won’t call,But I set up everything right am I missing a trigger or something? Could someone please point me in the right direction I’ve been trying to build this api for about 4 Months.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Vonage = require('@vonage/server-sdk');
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();
const vonage = new Vonage({
  apiKey: process.env.VONAGE_API_KEY,
  apiSecret: process.env.VONAGE_API_SECRET,
  applicationId: process.env.VONAGE_APPLICATION_ID,
  privateKey: process.env.VONAGE_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH
});

app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/call', (req, res) => {
  vonage.calls.create({
    to: [{
      type: 'phone',
      number: process.env.TO_NUMBER
    }],
    from: {
      type: 'phone',
      number: process.env.VONAGE_NUMBER,
    },
    ncco: [{
      "action": "talk",
      "text": "This is a text to speech call from Vonage"
    }]
  }, (error, response) => {
    if (error) console.error(error)
    if (response) console.log(response)
  });
  res.json('ok');
});

app.post('/event', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send('');
});

app.post('/answer', (req, res) => {
  const number = req.body.from.split('').join(' ');
  const ncco = [
    {
      action: 'talk',
      text: 'Thank you for calling from ' + number,
      language: 'en-IN',
      style: '4'
    },
    {
      action: 'stream',
      streamUrl: [
        'https://www.albinoblacksheep.com/audio/mp3/RickRollMarioPaint.mp3'
      ]
    }
  ];
  res.json(ncco);
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(Running on port ${process.env.PORT}));
```